# Quelle est la différence entre "dans la soirée" et "durant dans la soirée"?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, locutions, différence

Je suis tombé sur des phrases où la locution " **durant  dans la soirée**" est utilisée. Au début, Je me suis dit que ça devait être une erreur. Toutefois, j'ai aussi trouvé des usages de cette phrase-là même dans des journaux :

> " Cette animation bucolique, animée par Marie Mathurin, de la LPO (Ligue protectrice des oiseaux), vous permettra d'écouter les oiseaux deux heures **durant dans la soirée** et d'en apprendre plus sur nos petits amis à plumes." : [Ref](https://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2017/06/01/2585218-a-la-decouverte-de-nos-amis-a-plumes.html)

> " ... et juste avant que le ministre soviétique des affaires étrangères ne déclare à la tribune qu'un deuxième sommet Reagan-Gorbatchev était une "possibilité réaliste", ensuite une heure et demie **durant dans la soirée**, au siège de la mission soviétique auprès de l'Organisation internationale.":  [Ref](https://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/1986/09/25/l-affaire-daniloff-semble-approcher-d-une-solution_2929767_1819218.html)

> "Ils ont ensuite enregistré comment bien de verres les personnes buvaient **durant dans la soirée**" : [Ref](https://parismatch.be/actualites/societe/100490/cest-prouve-on-danserait-mieux-apres-une-bouteille-de-vin)

Donc, quelle est la différence entre " **dans la soirée**" et "**durant dans la soirée**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette combinaison est trompeuse ; "durant" est une  préposition qui peut être   postposée, bien qu'assez rarement.

> ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/durant)) I.− Durant, prép. de temps, antéposée ou, plus rarement, postposée.

Le sens est le même que lorsque le placement de la préposition est normal .

- ensuite durant une heure et demie dans la soirée

La troisième phrase contient deux  erreurs (« comment bien » ne se dit pas, il n'y a pas de régime pour la préposition « durant »).

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre explication !!!